# Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined in $http.put

Tags: angularjs

I am stuck in my angular application. I am getting error as " Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined" in my $http.put request. I have seen other posts related to this error. As per those posts, it is due to invalid header present in request. But in my case, the header is valid as my other request with the same header is working.
My controller code is as follows:

```
angular.module('myWebApp').controller('updateAccountController',
    function ($scope, $rootScope, $location,authFactory) {
        $scope.updateAccount = function () {
            authFactory
                    .updateAccount($scope.firstName, $scope.lastName, $scope.country)
                    .success(function (data) {});
        };
    }
);
```

My service is as follows:

```
var BASE = 'https://abc.com/';
angular.module('myWebApp').factory('authFactory',
    function ($location, $http) {
        var factory = {};

        factory.updateAccount = function (firstName, lastName, country) {
            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
                }
            };

            var userData = '{"type":"AccountDetails","firstName":"' + firstName +
                           '","lastName":"' + lastName + 
                           '","country":"' + country + '"}';

            return $http.put(BASE + 'account', config, userData);
        };

        return factory;
    }
);
```

Please, help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please consider reformatting the code in your question for improved readability. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the arguments to **[`$http.put()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#put)** in the wrong order.

Instead of: `$http.put(BASE + 'account', config, userData);`

It should be: `$http.put(BASE + 'account', userData, config);`